# Separate output files of cdk8s synth

Tags: python, kubernetes, yaml, cdk8s

The following code will create one yaml file `dist/clusterip.k8s.yaml` contains all my defines of deployment and statefulset, is there way to separate different files in output such as `dist/clusterip.k8s.yaml` and `dist/statefulset.k8s.yaml`?

```
class MyChart(Chart):
    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, id: str):
        super().__init__(scope, id)
        ClusterIp(self, 'clusterip')
        StateFulSet(self, 'statefulset')

app = App()
MyChart(app, "clusterip")
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not exactly what you want to hear but cdk8s creates one output file per chart. So you could split resources over multiple charts within your app.

As your personal workaround you also could split the yaml documents per file on your own. When you already have started using Python, that should be simple as `yaml.safe_load` the output file, loop over all documents and `yaml.safe_dump` them again. Between load and dump you can organize things as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is.

It has been implemented in this commit: https://github.com/cdk8s-team/cdk8s-core/commit/474e373c1b86a57a3568cca0f9629e038266f2d5

From https://github.com/cdk8s-team/cdk8s-core/blob/d00d2de5816106ea8bb7259e4ee5da907bc83e2a/src/app.ts:

```
/** The method to divide YAML output into files */
export enum YamlOutputType {
  /** All resources are output into a single YAML file */
  FILE_PER_APP,
  /** Resources are split into seperate files by chart */
  FILE_PER_CHART,
  /** Each resource is output to its own file */
  FILE_PER_RESOURCE,
  /** Each chart in its own folder and each resource in its own file */
  FOLDER_PER_CHART_FILE_PER_RESOURCE,
}

export interface AppProps {
  /**
   * The directory to output Kubernetes manifests.
   *
   * @default - CDK8S_OUTDIR if defined, otherwise "dist"
   */
  readonly outdir?: string;
  /**
   *  The file extension to use for rendered YAML files
   * @default .k8s.yaml
   */
  readonly outputFileExtension?: string;
  /**
   *  How to divide the YAML output into files
   * @default YamlOutputType.FILE_PER_CHART
   */
  readonly yamlOutputType?: YamlOutputType;
}
```